# Object Invisible But Normals Visible?

Tags: texturing, transparency, normals

How would I set it up so that only the normal map is visible on an object?

[image: The blue object has the normals I want to overlay onto the object behind it.]

There's two objects, one has the normals, and underneath is the object I want to overlay the normals onto. I want to make it so that everything on the first object is invisible except for the shading from the normal map.

Comment: pls provide blend file because you didn't provide enough useful information so that we know what you did

Comment: Donyou mean you want to transfer the normals from object 1 to object 2?